# Referencing type in different namespace with same prefix generates CS0234 error

Tags: c#

I'm confused why the following C# code won't compile, and instead generates the following:

`error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Module' does not exist in the namespace 'SomeName.Module.SomeName' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

```
using System;

namespace SomeName.Module.AnotherName
{
    public struct SomeStruct
    {
    }
}

namespace SomeName.Module.SomeName
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        struct SomeNestedType
        {
            void SomeMethod(in SomeName.Module.AnotherName.SomeStruct someStruct) 
            { 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not aware of any namespace rules that would prevent it from finding the fully-qualified `SomeName.Module.AnotherName.SomeStruct` type.

Comment: When you say "generates the following (error)", it would be nice for you to point out on which line the compiler finds issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `SomeName` is being resolved as the *final* part of the namespace `SomeName.Module.SomeName`, and `Module` is being resolved relative to that.

If you absolutely can't change your namespaces, you can use the `global` namespace alias to disambiguate:

```cs
void SomeMethod(in global::SomeName.Module.AnotherName.SomeStruct someStruct)
```

However, it would be better to just use different names. For example, if you have namespaces of `SomeName1.Module.AnotherName` and `SomeName1.Module.SomeName2` you don't get this problem - and the code will be easier for *humans* to read as well as the compiler. (Obviously it wouldn't actually be that name, but I can only hope that you're not *really* using `SomeName` in the first place. Pick good but different names for the two parts of the namespace.)

Comment: Thanks!  I'd totally forgotten about the need to explicitly qualify them with the global namespace.
In this case we are source-generating around user code, so we can't choose the namespace names.